# 前年比または増減率を求めるプログラムを教えてください。

Tags: r

rで前年比または増減率を求めるプログラムを作りたいのですが、どう処理すればいいのかわからず困っています。
データは教育用標準データセットのssdseを使っており、以下の様な内容です。
（仮に人口の増減率を知りたいとします。ただし、人口の増減率を知りたいわけではないので気にしないでください。）

```
年度　　都道府県　　人口　　面積
2016   北海道　　　〇〇〇　××
2015   北海道　　　〇〇〇　××
2014   北海道　　　〇〇〇　××
…
2005   北海道
2016   青森県　　　〇〇　　××
以下同様
```

都道府県はfactor、年度や人口、ほかのものはint型になっています。
最初はmutateを使おうとしましたが、mutateは一括で列を追加するものなのでうまくいきませんでした。また、summariseやapply関数も考えましたが同じようにうまくいきませんでした。
前年比の定義としては2016年の人口/2015年の人口というように考えています。

些細なことでもいいのでよろしくお願いします。

以下のプログラムはmutate関数で作ったプログラムです。（4列目に人口があります。2016年～2005年で12年分のデータがあります。）

```
for(i in 1:12){
  if(i==12){
    ss[i,]<-filter(ssdse,都道府県=="北海道")%>%
      mutate(前年比=NA)
  }
  else{
    ss[i,]<-filter(ssdse,都道府県=="北海道")%>%
      mutate(前年比=ssdse[i,4]/ssdse[i+1,4])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

↓dplyrパッケージのgroup_byとlag関数を用いた例です。

```r
library(dplyr)

# デモデータ作成
df <- data.frame(
  year = rep(seq(2005, 2016), 2),
  pref = as.factor(rep(c("北海道", "青森県"), each = 12)),
  pop = as.integer(runif(12 * 2, 100, 200))
)


print(df)
#>    year   pref pop
#> 1  2005 北海道 176
#> 2  2006 北海道 149
...
#> 11 2015 北海道 110
#> 12 2016 北海道 126
#> 13 2005 青森県 109
#> 14 2006 青森県 127
...
#> 23 2015 青森県 135
#> 24 2016 青森県 125

# 都道府県別人口増加率算出
df %>% 
  # 都道府県別に集計
  dplyr::group_by(pref) %>% 
  # 年度で並び替え
  dplyr::arrange(year) %>% 
  # 増加率(当年の人口/前年の人口)算出
  dplyr::mutate(
    rate = pop/dplyr::lag(pop)
  )
#> # A tibble: 24 x 4
#> # Groups:   pref [2]
#>     year pref     pop   rate
#>    <int> <fct>  <int>  <dbl>
#>  1  2005 北海道   176 NA    
#>  2  2005 青森県   109 NA    
#>  3  2006 北海道   149  0.847
#>  4  2006 青森県   127  1.17 
#>  5  2007 北海道   162  1.09 
#>  6  2007 青森県   155  1.22 
...
```